# Use of word "buy" as focus keyword

Tags: seo, ecommerce

I am building an e-commerce Website using WooCommerce and Yoast SEO.

I am looking at the competition and I noticed that in my industry, if you type *"buy adidas stan smith"* on Google, results that appear at the top do not necessarily include the word **"buy"**.

Therefore, is it necessary to use the word "buy" within a focus keyphrase ? Does that really matter a lot for the SEO of a product page ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll find that with purchase searches, the user's intent behind the search is more important than the actual wording itself. Google skips over the direct wording of the search and asks the question more directly: "What is the sort of user who typed in that query looking for? Why did the user conduct this search? What is the user trying to accomplish?"

In the case of a search such as "buy adidas", Google is smart enough to know that the user is trying to buy a pair of shoes in an online or local shop. Google effectively ignores the word "buy" as a direct keyword, because the algorithm intuitively knows that the word "buy" just means "show this user a way to purchase the item represented by the rest of their search query".

In the case of the "buy" keyword it's much less about the keyword itself and much more about whether your website allows its users to purchase what they are looking for.

More information about search intent:

https://yoast.com/search-intent/

Comment: Thank you @Maximillian for your answer. Therefore for an online shop, what is more relevant ? 1) Include the word "buy" in the focus keyphrase ("buy adidas stan smith") to match the search intent of online buyers ? Or 2) Use a keyphrase without the word "buy" ("adidas stan smith") and include the word several times throughout the product page's content ?
YOAST requires to include the focus keyphrase in the first paragraph. But it is quite difficult to make logical sentences (grammatically correct) with the focus keyphrase from a). Most of the time I have to use "buy a pair of..."

Comment: @CJ42 I'm kind of old fashioned maybe, but my advice is to design for users first and search engines second. Instead of contorting your copy around a key phrase that is difficult to use grammatically, pepper in key words while still keeping the user's reading experience paramount. But I tend to be less aggressive with my SEO so I can't guarantee this is the best approach.

Comment: By the way, my intuition says nobody really types in "buy a pair of shoes", they just type "buy shoes". But maybe that's just my age group.